# Downloading a string as a text file works only once per render? (React)

Tags: reactjs, file, download

I have a string in a state which I would want to download when clicking a download button. My current code kinda works but for some reason it works only once per render meaning that it won't download the file again unless I refresh the page?

```
 const element = document.createElement("a");
    element.setAttribute("id", "download-link");
    const file = new Blob([content], { type: "text/plain" });
    element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    element.download = "mySubtitles.vtt";

    // simulate link click
    document.body.appendChild(element); // Required for this to work in FireFox
    element.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because each time the function is executed a new link is appended to your DOM.
add this line at the end of your function:

```js
document.body.removeChild(element);
```